# MonoTouch App to Mono Android

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am new to Mono and my first Question is, if it´s possible to create an App in Monotouch and then build it for iOS, Android and Windows Phone?! What i mean is, can i have one source code?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly. If you build your application using a [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)-like model then you can easily share a **lot** of code between all those platforms.

A very good example of this is Xamarin's [MWC 2012 sample application](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/24/mwc_2012/). It shows you how you can reuse almost everything, except the UI, for iPhone, iPad, Android and Windows Phone applications.

Comment: +1 for this answer. Also add a mention for gshackle's recent xaminar now on youtube, and for the xamarin's mobile samples on GitHub - and for the monocross and mvvmcross samples.